# Python script inserting into MySQL Table

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert

I've been working on a python script that pulls and organizes data from a website, and then attempts to reproduce that data in a MySQL table.  For the purposes of this question, this table's name is "capacitors", but I intend to eventually have more tables for more categories.

The one thing I can't seem to get around is inserting the data into the MySQL table.  My script runs properly (at least I think so) until the sql execute statement in which it only adds one row to the table.  It should add a total of 5 rows according to the for loop at the top of the script.  **EDIT:** **What I'm really looking for here is to be able to update existing rows with new information from the website, as well as add entirely new rows.**

Can I have some advice as to what I'm missing here?  Let me know if you need anything other than the script, which is below.  Thanks!!

```
import stock_checker, json, urllib.request, pprint, os, csv, re, time
import mysql.connector as my

# Create list of parts that will be looked up in Octopart 
parts=[]
for k in range(len(stock_checker.d)):
    parts.append((stock_checker.d[k]["product_id"]))

# THIS NEXT PART NEEDS TO HAPPEN FOR EACH PIECE
for i in range(5):
    print ("Generating detailed part information on: %s" % parts[i])

    url = 'http://octopart.com/api/v3/parts/match?'
    url += '&queries=[{"mpn":"' + parts[i] + '"}]'
    url += '&apikey=1b0d5753'
    url += '&include[]=specs'

    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    response = json.loads(data)

    #print request time (in milliseconds)
    # print response['msec']

    debug=False
    if debug:
        pprint.pprint(response)

    # print mpn's
    mylisth= ['part_number'] #list of headers
    mylistv= [parts[0]] #list of values
    mydict = {} #dictionary of pairs
    headers = []
    for result in response['results']:
        for item in result['items']:
            for key,value in item['specs'].items():
                try:
                    mydict.update({key:value['display_value']})
                    mylisth.append(key)
                    mylistv.append(value['display_value'])

                    print ("%s: %s" % (key, value['display_value']))
                    #print("%s" % (value['display_value']))

                except KeyError as e:
                    print ("WARNING: Could not find Key for %s in key \"%s\". Value is %s" % (e, key, value))

    print ("")

    #vector of what all the headers should look like
    try:
        if mylisth[1] == 'capacitance':
            cap_headers = ['part_number','capacitance','capacitance_tolerance','case_package','case_package_si','dielectric_characteristic',
                        'dielectric_material', 'lead_free_status','lifecycle_status','mounting_style','operating_temperature','packaging','pin_count',
                       'reach_svhc_compliance','rohs_status','size_height','size_length','size_thickness','size_width','voltage_rating_dc']

            missing = list(set(cap_headers)-set(mylisth))

            for i in range(len(missing)):   
                mylisth.insert(cap_headers.index(missing[i]), missing[i])
                mylistv.insert(cap_headers.index(missing[i]), None)
        if mylisth[2] == 'inductance':
            ind_headers = ['part_number','case_package','inductance','lead_free_status','mounting_style','packaging',
                           'pin_count','rohs_status']
    except:
        print("ERROR: BYE! HAVE A GOOD TIME! ;)")

    #Remove Units
    #if mylisth[1]=='capacitance':
        #mylistv[2]=re.sub("[^0-9]","",mylistv[2])

    time.sleep(1)

    #######################################################################################################

    #connect to database
    cnx = my.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='',database='mydb')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    #create string input of mylisth
    heads = ','.join(str(i) for i in mylisth)

    #create string input of %s corresponding to number of entries in mylisth
    placelst = ['%s' for i in mylisth]
    placestr = ','.join(str(i) for i in placelst)

    #add_capacitor -> SQL query line // data_capacitor -> values to be inserted using query line
    add_capacitor = ("INSERT IGNORE INTO capacitors ("+heads+") VALUES ("+placestr+")")
    data_capacitor = mylistv

    cursor.execute(add_capacitor, data_capacitor)
    emp_no = cursor.lastrowid

    cnx.commit()

    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

Comment: Have you already saved data on your db? The problem with `INSERT IGNORE` is that your data won't be inserted if it already exists. Also, can you try debugging if `placestr` contains the information you need (and in the correct structure)?

Comment: placestr should be correct, I'm not getting any sql syntax errors.  The data is already saved to the database actually, at least one row of it is.  What I really need is a way to update existing rows with new information from the website and insert entirely new rows...

Comment: have you tried to put a UNIQUE constraint on your field you dont want duplicate then use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: did you do this on purpose? every iteration using parts[0] instead of parts[i]. mylistv= [parts[0]] #list of values

Comment: @JialinZou, yes that is on purpose